# Use display as bounding box with eevee

Tags: game-engine, eevee-render-engine

my issue is that I have a scene with many objects for a game with Eevee (UPBGE), and I cannot afford to display them in the viewport, even though I put together a few logic bricks that emulate a binary LOD (visible/invisible) so that in-game doesn't lag from having to draw distant objects.
I wanted to use `Object Properties > Viewport Display > Bounds` but Eevee doesn't render the meshes when the game starts.
When using the 'visibility' logic node, effects are taken into account and it is stated that the node acts upon the render switch button from the outliner, but manually setting this switch outside of the game has not effects, thus I don't understand how the game engine treats Eevee viewport's render.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an answer to your problem's issue, but likely one of the UPBGE developers would have an answer. Feel free to drop by on UPBGE Discord and ask them.
https://discord.me/upbge

Comment: What I ended up doing is generating the ground patch in-game, since bpy works with UPBGE, but this issue is not solved. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but for view bound meshes, even though Blender doesn't render those polygon faces, they still render the vertices points for meshes, which is still a performance hazard. By the way, I totally forgot the wireframe modifier works at run-time for 0.3x. Does this solve your problem?

[image]

Comment: No the bounding box display in object's settings cannot be used unless I switch it to textured once the game starts, which -no that you made me think about it- the best solution for demanding scenes (since we can use bpy in script with 3.x).